# BV analogue with well-factorable function. (Primes in arithmetic progression)

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory

Is this special case known?
For $\lambda(q)$ -- well-factorable function and $q|P(z)$, $\pi(x;q,a)$ $a=1$.
$\displaystyle \sum_{q\leq x^{1-\epsilon}} \lambda(q) ( \pi (x;q,1)-\frac{\pi(x)}{\varphi (q)} )\leq \frac{Cx}{\log^A(x) }$

Comment: You should edit your old question https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356043/primes-in-arithmetic-progression and ask for it to be reopened, rather than starting a new post

Comment: I do not know how.

Comment: When you go to your old question, do you see any options for editing? Perhaps you may need to register as a user first, a move which I would strongly recommend since it prevents the proliferation of multiple user accounts and duplicate questions

Comment: I did not register. I remember something similar to my question in some article(for $a=1$). But I don’t remember where and how much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Primes in arithmetic progression](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/356043/primes-in-arithmetic-progression)

Comment: What is a well-factorable function? What is $P(z)$?

Comment: I have found the partial answer. If you remove this $\lambda(q)$ function and not take modulo, then you can take $1-\epsilon$. See: Fouvry  Sur le problème des diviseurs de Titchmarsh. 1985 But with this function i do not how to get such result.

Comment: Both links are broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This type was proved by Bombieri, Friedlander and Iwaniec in the paper "*Primes in arithmetic progressions to large moduli*.